# SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 1: Self signed certificates in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am using sample code provided by gsoap for SSL on Windows. I have successfully generated all required certificates, and I installed certificate on Windows in trusted root certificate directory. The problem I encounter is that self signed certificates are not accepted on windows. The process is terminated in handshake.

When I run client and server, I get the error on client side:

> SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth 1: Self signed certificates in certificate chain
>   certificate issuer
>   certificate subject

Comment: Which sample exactly did you try? gsoap\samples\ssl?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same contents as in ssl folder

Answer (score 0):

It looks issuer and subject fields are both empty and, therefore, equal.
Both Certs, ca and client  should be reissued with subj field set.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt , we need to run the winscp command manually . it will prompt to accept certificate. subsequent execution will work